# Is there a way to remove the boilerplate in Slick GetResult?

Tags: scala, slick

This is a common pattern when using slick SQL

```
implicit private val mapper = GetResult[MyClass]{r =>
  MyClass(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<?, r.<<?, r.<<?, r.<<)
}
```

**Is there a way to write something much cleaner, without the boilerplate?** e.g.

```
implicit private val mapper = GetResult[MyClass]
```

when `MyClass` is a case class.

Comment: This is probably a bit more complicated than you think. You could probably write a macro for this but it would only work in the most simple case where the case class is flat (no nested case classes) and perfectly maps to the table you are selecting from.

Comment: That macro could be itself implicit, working for any case class you feed to it, obviating the need for writing `implicit val ...` again and again. In my recent talks (http://scalamacros.org/paperstalks.html) I elaborate on this technique in detail. The macro can also report errors if its type parameter denotes a class that's not supported.

Comment: All in all, if you provide more details about the task at hand, I could write the implicit macro for you.

Comment: Indeed, a macro for this should be pretty simple to write. I think useful semantics would be: Use r.<<? for any case class field of Option[_] type unless it is followed by a non-Option field (The example given above does not make much sense), otherwise use r.<<. Nested objects should be handled automatically because << and <<? will search for an implicit GetResult for the type of the field. AFAIK there is no common base class for case classes, so the implicit macro would need to accept at least Product and have a lower priority so that the predefined implicits win.

Comment: Wouldn't it be case for something `extract(MyClass.apply _)` and extract been overloaded with all 22 tuples?

Comment: Actually all 22 functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be an overwhelming tendency for people to answer in comments on SO these days (afraid of downvotes?). In conclusion, no there is no shortcut.

**UPDATE**: today we would use https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/6875-workshop-shapeless-for-mortals

Comment: so silly that there is none, since the `Table` object already contains a mapping from rows to object (usually the `*` method)

Comment: I'm actually quite certain that I could trivially do this with a bit of shapeless magic. `LabelledGeneric` would do the trick.

Comment: I got this working here https://github.com/joprice/shapeless-getresult/blob/master/src/main/scala/GenGetResult.scala based on an hlist example from https://github.com/d6y/slickless-hlist-getresult.